# Html extension method with razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Have trouble with creating a extension method which takes Razor syntax as parameter in MVC3

```
@Html.Test(x=>x.UserName, () => @<div>Here goes something</div>)
```

What is the extension method signature:

```
public static IHtmlString Test<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, ????????)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that what you are trying to accomplish is possible. Razor syntax is a way to use C# within a HTML page. You are already using Razor syntax by calling the `Html.Test` helper. Everything inside `Html.Test(...)` is C#.

So why not use something like this?

```
@Html.Test(x=>x.UserName, "<div>Here goes something</div>")

public static IHtmlString Test<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string html)
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Yes, that is an option, but I would like to use the razor template syntax in the markup